# Toolbar appears on bottom of the screen and not at top

Tags: python, kivymd

my `MDtoolbar` appear at the bottom of the screen and not appearing at the top.. I am using python 3.7

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

screen_main="""
Screen :
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : "vertical"
        MDToolbar : 
            title : "KSFE"


"""
class KSFEApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        scr = Builder.load_string(screen_main)
        return scr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KSFEApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add another widget to the `BoxLayout` (which you probably will do anyways).

For example:

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

screen_main = """
Screen:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar: 
            title: "KSFE"
        
        MDLabel:
"""


class KSFEApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        scr = Builder.load_string(screen_main)
        return scr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KSFEApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure why but `MDToolbar` seems unhappy within `BoxLayout`.

If you take it out of the `BoxLayout` so it's just in Screen and give it the attribute `pos_hint = {"top": 1}` so that it's like:

```
screen_main="""
Screen :
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : "vertical"
        MDToolbar : 
            title : "KSFE"
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
 
"""
```

Then it should position itself correctly.